# Column 'Document Id' not added to Library even after activating 'Document ID Service'

Tags: 2010, feature, document-id

To enable document id feature in SP10, I followed the steps mentioned in the following posts:

1. [Document ID in SharePoint Server 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/document-id-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)
2. [SharePoint 2010 – Activating the Document ID Feature](http://miketangoblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/sharepoint-2010-activating-the-document-id-feature/)
3. [Why after I enable the Document ID Service Feature do I not see Document ID's on my documents?](http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/11/why-after-i-enable-document-id-service.html)

Still, the column `'Document Id'` is not added to the libraries.

Any hint on what might I be missing?

This forum [Document ID feature not working](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/5a992581-41bf-4cf8-9c6d-8005d23931f0) is also of no help.

**Edited**: The column is present in site collection created after enabling the feature. The problem exists only for the existing sites.

Comment: Have you waited 30 minutes after activating the feature before running the timer jobs? If the Site collection is large SharePoint put a 30 minute delay into the WorkItems to be processed by the timer jobs

Comment: the column is present in the freshly created site collection.(ie the site coll created after the timer jobs viz Document ID assignment job, Document ID enable/disable job were run)

Comment: @PerJakobsen: Thanks for the reply. I waited more than 2 hours, still the column was not added.

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming that you have followed activating the Document ID Feature as described in your links above and/or here - [SharePoint 2010 – Activating the Document ID Feature](http://miketangoblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/sharepoint-2010-activating-the-document-id-feature/). And also, recycling the timer jobs.

The next would be to examine if the Document ID feature has been properly deployed to your Documents library. You could use the [SharePoint 2010 Manager (Explorer)](http://spm.codeplex.com/) or use the PowerShell snippet below for details (line 1 shows the Doc ID feature, line 4 shows Doc ID fields in the Documents library and line 5 shows Doc ID Event receivers to the Documents Library) :

1. Get-SPFeature -Site http://fooSiteCollection | where {$_.DisplayName -eq "DocId"} | fl
2. $fooSite = Get-SPWeb http://fooSiteURL
3. $fooList = $fooSite.Lists["Documents"]
4. $foolist.Fields   | where {$_.Title -eq "Document ID"} | fl
5. $foolist.EventReceivers |  where {$_.Name -eq "Document ID Generator"} | ft

Comment: Thanks @sbc111 for the reply.
I checked with SP manager and the Column 'Document Id' was not found. Also the eventReceiver 'Document ID Generator' was not present. 
so, does it mean the feature was not properly deployed (but the feature is shown as activated) ?

Comment: I would think so - you may want to try to deactivate and activate again the Document ID feature, presuming that you got some results back in Line #1 for the site collection. What version of SharePoint 2010 server are you using (Std/Ent) ?

Comment: -I deactivated and activated the feature multiple times (restarted the server, reset iis as well) but no result.
-I did not check with Powershell but in SP Manager, the feature was shown as activated in the site collection.
-I am using Standard version of SP.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds silly, but best not to overlook the obvious: do you have another column called "DocumentID" or "Document ID" in the site column gallery?

Comment: No such column was present.